# Why does xdebug profiling in php does not create any output files?

Tags: php, linux, xdebug

I am trying to create xdebug output files with php 5.2 as described [enter link description here](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler). I added the following line to the correct `php.ini` file:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
```

When I start the PHP script (CLI) as root, no file starting with `cachegrind.out` is generated in the `/tmp` directory. Since I do not have any issues with rights as running with root, why don't I get any  xdebug output file?

Additional information:

- No, I cannot uYse PHP 5.3
- Yes, xdebug seems to be enabled somehow (when I try to put a line `zend_extension=.../xdebug.so` in `php.ini` I am reminded that this extension is already loaded.)
- `phpinfo()` tells me that `profiler_enable` is OFF. Is there a way to turn it on again in the php code itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that xdebug (and its options) have been compiled into php. A possibility to enable this particular xdebug option when running a php code is to use the -d switch of php:

```
php5 -d xdebug.profiler_enable=on mycode.php
```